# Removing XML data based on divs being hidden using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, domdocument

Okay this is quite complicated to explain but i'll try and keep it as short as possible. I'm making an 'app', part of the function of which is to pull XML based data from a file using PHP `DOMDocument()` and a loop to display each block of information in its own DIV. My aim is to allow the user to then click a 'close' button on any of these displayed div's and they will be hidden using jQuery similar to this:

```
$('input[name=foo]').live('change', function(){
     if ( $(this).is(":checked")) {
         $('.bar').hide(500);
     }
```

I'm pretty certain I can get it up to this stage with no issues however, when the user saves at the end of this process I want to pass params back that relate to the boxes that have been hidden/removed using `$_POST` and then subsequently remove the corresponding items/nodes from the original xml document. Each item and each close button has a unique ID.

Any tips on how to achieve this would be much appreicated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

just get the ids or names of the div that have hidden and send that as POST and then go to their parent element. suppose their parent node is referenced in `$parent` and the node u want to remove is referenced in `$child`. Now use `$parent->removeChild($child)`

or u can do this 
get the node reference say `$node`
then use

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer as it's the most logical for me in terms of what i already have. It's going to take me a while to get this section implemented and working to a point where i can say whether this is the right answer for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is that you can check whether the `div` is hidden or not like `$(".bar").is(':hidden');` and then not include it in the XML you're sending back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm confident that I can check which ones are hidden etc the problem for me is, its being displayed in a dynamically produced table and I just want to pass back the id's of the hidden div's and then have them removed from the originally uploaded xml file, sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When one of the boxes is clicked, do a xmlhttprequest using the post method.

[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) pasing the ID and state of the box.